# mocking and testing a single method in the class (MagicMock/py.test)

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I want to write a test for a single method in class (let's say it is a 'str' class):

```
   mocked_str = mock.MagicMock(str)
   str.__len__(mocked_str)
```

But it fails:

```
TypeError: descriptor '__len__' requires a 'str' object but received a 'MagicMock'
```

How can I mock whole class except a single function from it (for testing)? Thanks.

Comment: I've given a tentative answer, but the question is very unclear. Which is the class + method you're trying to test? A better example would help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have it the wrong way around. mocked_str is the object you just mocked and `__len__` is the mocked method on it:

```
>>> mocked_str.__len__('foo')
0
```